# JavaCamera2View pinch zoom

Tags: android, opencv, zooming, android-camera2

Iam implementing JavaCamera2View in opencv face-detection sample.
the app able to get the pinch action and recognize, and calculate the size of Rect. However the screen does not zoomed in or out at all. just nothing happend.
so i creane new class that implement JavaCamera2View so that i have more space to code my own code.

so in my FdActivity implement OnTouchListener i do :

```java
private zoomcameraview   mOpenCvCameraView;
.
.


mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
mOpenCvCameraView.setOnTouchListener(FdActivity.this);
.
.
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        return mOpenCvCameraView.setTouch(view,motionEvent, String.valueOf(cameraId));

    }
```

and inside zoomcameraview implement JavaCamera2View i do :

```java
 private float getFingerSpacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }


    public boolean setTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent, String camId) {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder = getmPreviewRequestBuilder();
        mCaptureSession = getmCaptureSession();
        Log.d("run on touch iside", "onTouch: motion count " +motionEvent.getPointerCount());
        try {

            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(camId);
            float maxzoom = (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM))*10;

            Rect m = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
            int action = motionEvent.getAction();
            float current_finger_spacing;

            if (motionEvent.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                // Multi touch logic
                current_finger_spacing = getFingerSpacing(motionEvent);
                Log.d("finger", "setTouch: " + finger_spacing);
                if(finger_spacing != 0){
                    if(current_finger_spacing > finger_spacing && maxzoom > zoom_level){
                        zoom_level++;
                    } else if (current_finger_spacing < finger_spacing && zoom_level > 1){
                        zoom_level--;
                    }
                    Log.d("zoom level", "setTouch: " + zoom_level);
                    int minW = (int) (m.width() / maxzoom);
                    int minH = (int) (m.height() / maxzoom);
                    int difW = m.width() - minW;
                    int difH = m.height() - minH;
                    int cropW = difW /100 *(int)zoom_level;
                    int cropH = difH /100 *(int)zoom_level;
                    cropW -= cropW & 3;
                    cropH -= cropH & 3;
                    Rect zoom = new Rect(cropW, cropH, m.width() - cropW, m.height() - cropH);
                    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoom);
                }
                finger_spacing = current_finger_spacing;
            } else{
                return true;
//                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
//                    return true;
//                    //single touch logic
//                }
            }

            try {
                mCaptureSession
                        .setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), null, getmBackgroundHandler());
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("can not access camera.", e);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and inside JavaCamera2View i set getter and setter

```java
public CaptureRequest.Builder getmPreviewRequestBuilder() {
        return mPreviewRequestBuilder;
    }

    public void setmPreviewRequestBuilder(CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder) {
        this.mPreviewRequestBuilder = mPreviewRequestBuilder;
    }

    public CameraCaptureSession getmCaptureSession() {
        return mCaptureSession;
    }

    public void setmCaptureSession(CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession) {
        this.mCaptureSession = mCaptureSession;
    }

    public CameraDevice.StateCallback getmStateCallback() {
        return mStateCallback;
    }

    public Handler getmBackgroundHandler() {
        return mBackgroundHandler;
    }

    public void setmBackgroundHandler(Handler mBackgroundHandler) {
        this.mBackgroundHandler = mBackgroundHandler;
    }
```

i am not sure what is wrong, but the zoom does not implemented but no error.

Answer (score 0):

sorry again, after days of trying i solve it.
implement

```java
public boolean setTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent, String camId) {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder = getmPreviewRequestBuilder();
        mCaptureSession = getmCaptureSession();
        Log.d("run on touch iside", "onTouch: motion count " +motionEvent.getPointerCount());
        try {

            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(camId);
            float maxzoom = (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM))*10;

            Rect m = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
            int action = motionEvent.getAction();
            float current_finger_spacing;

            if (motionEvent.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                // Multi touch logic
                current_finger_spacing = getFingerSpacing(motionEvent);
                Log.d("finger", "setTouch: " + finger_spacing);
                if(finger_spacing != 0){
                    if(current_finger_spacing > finger_spacing && maxzoom > zoom_level){
                        zoom_level++;
                    } else if (current_finger_spacing < finger_spacing && zoom_level > 1){
                        zoom_level--;
                    }
                    Log.d("zoom level", "setTouch: " + zoom_level);
                    int minW = (int) (m.width() / maxzoom);
                    int minH = (int) (m.height() / maxzoom);
                    int difW = m.width() - minW;
                    int difH = m.height() - minH;
                    int cropW = difW /100 *(int)zoom_level;
                    int cropH = difH /100 *(int)zoom_level;
                    cropW -= cropW & 3;
                    cropH -= cropH & 3;
                    Rect zoom = new Rect(cropW, cropH, m.width() - cropW, m.height() - cropH);
                    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoom);
                }
                finger_spacing = current_finger_spacing;
            } else{
                return true;
//                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
//                    return true;
//                    //single touch logic
//                }
            }

            try {
                mCaptureSession
                        .setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), null, getmBackgroundHandler());
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("can not access camera.", e);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

directly on FdAcitvity solve my problem.
now opencv android with camera2 and pich zoom is correctly implemented

thanks